# Handling messages along with long-term retry policy

Tags: rabbitmq, masstransit

Greetings to MT experts.

In my app I have default retry policy that sends message each 3 minutes for 30 minutes in total. And if there are many failed messages that are affected with this policy (more than 16) other messages are not handled (even successfull ones). This is a huge problem, because if there are 16 broken messages, then whole queue is blocked for 30 minutes.

I'm sure there is a solution for this, but I haven't found any.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution is redelivery aka second-level retries.

Here is the [documentation](http://masstransit-project.com/MassTransit/usage/scheduling/redeliver.html).

There are two ways to use it:

Explicit redelivery from a consumer, called on exception:

```
public async Task Consume(ConsumeContext<ScheduleNotification> context)
{
    try
    {
        // try to update the database
    }
    catch (CustomerNotFoundException exception)
    {
        // schedule redelivery in one minute
        context.Redeliver(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1));
    }
}
```

Or using configuration and policy (part of the endpoint configuration delegate):

```
ep.Consumer<CSomeConsumer>(c => c.Message<SomeMessage>(
    x => x.UseDelayedRedelivery(
        p =>
        {
            p.Handle<SqlException>(e => e.Message.Contains("Timeout"));
            p.Exponential(40, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10), TimeSpan.FromHours(1),
                TimeSpan.FromSeconds(4));
        })));
```

Remember that you must have [scheduling](http://masstransit-project.com/MassTransit/usage/scheduling/) configured to use this feature. It can be done using [Quartz](http://masstransit-project.com/MassTransit/usage/scheduling/scheduling-api.html) or [RabbitMQ](http://masstransit-project.com/MassTransit/usage/scheduling/rabbitmq-delayed.html)/[AzureSB](http://masstransit-project.com/MassTransit/usage/scheduling/azure-sb-scheduler.html) integrated scheduling features.

Comment: Thanks. It seems that we'll have to use this approach.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for the circuit breaker pattern, this can be applied to the masstransit with the following:

```
cfg.ReceiveEndpoint(host, "customer_update_queue", e =>
{
    e.UseCircuitBreaker(cb =>
    {
        cb.TrackingPeriod = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1);
        cb.TripThreshold = 15;
        cb.ActiveThreshold = 10;
        cb.ResetInterval = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5);
    });
    // other configuration
});
```

More information can be found in the docs: 
http://masstransit-project.com/MassTransit/advanced/middleware/circuit-breaker.html

Comment: Don't think it is exactly what I'm looking for. As far as I understood, the message will be consumed multiple times before required threshold is reached, and this is unacceptable in my case.